# XPath to HTML headers above a table?

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to get an XPATH string in my python script that will only give me headers `<h2>` that are above the table. I'm new to XPath but so far I know if I do something like `//h2//text()` I'll get all the headers. However is there any way to create the XPath so that it only takes headers `A`, `B` and not `C` ?

```
import lxml.html as html
import lxml.etree as etree

x="""
<h2> A</h2>
<table>...</table>
<h2> B </h2>
<table>..</table>
<h2> C </h2>
"""
xt = etree.fromstring(x, parser=html.HTMLParser(recover=True,remove_comments=True))
print xt.xpath("//h2/text()")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three alternatives for selecting the `A` and `B` `h2` elements:

1. This XPath,

   ```
   //h2[position() = 1 or position() = 2]
   ```

   will select the first two `h2` elements in the document.
2. This XPath,

   ```
   //h2[normalize-space()='A' or normalize-space()='B']
   ```

   will select those `h2` elements whose space-normalized string value is `"A"` or `"B"`.
3. This XPath,

   ```
   //h2[following-sibling::*[1][self::table]]
   ```

   will select those `h2` elements whose immediately following sibling is a `table` element.

Comment: If I wanted all table data right after the header what would be the xpath. Basically I'm trying to convert tables into csv and use the header to tag each csv file.

Comment: Please ask a new question and provide examples of exactly which data you'd like to select.  Just the immediately following table?  The whole table or only parts?  Ect.  Note that converting to CSV will require more than XPath.